# Deploy in production without running tests

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api

Salesforce has new parameters for the deploy option.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_api_meta_new_calls.htm

Can we deploy to production with no run test parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation in the link you provided which I assume you did not read regarding **No Tests**

> NoTestRun—No tests are run. This test level applies only to
>   deployments to development environments, such as sandbox, Developer
>   Edition, or trial organizations. This test level is the default for
>   development environments

Comment: It's worth including the **RunLocalTests** documentation as well as its the default for production environments.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** add the NoTestRun parameter to a deployment to a production environment, **but the tests will still be run** and they will need to pass.

When I did the deployment below with the testLevel set to NoTestRun, the deployment was successful, and checking the deployment status revealed that the tests were being run anyways. Interestingly when checking the deployment history in the ui, it said that tests weren't necessary rather than showing the summary of number of tests run (test failures still showed up in the list below on unsuccessful deployments).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <n1:SessionHeader xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <n1:sessionId><!--OMITTED--></n1:sessionId>
        </n1:SessionHeader>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <n1:deploy xmlns:n1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <n1:ZipFile type="xsd:base64Binary"><!--OMITTED--></n1:ZipFile>
            <n1:DeployOptions type="tns:DeployOptions">
                <n1:allowMissingFiles type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:allowMissingFiles>
                <n1:autoUpdatePackage type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:autoUpdatePackage>
                <n1:checkOnly type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:checkOnly>
                <n1:ignoreWarnings type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:ignoreWarnings>
                <n1:performRetrieve type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:performRetrieve>
                <n1:purgeOnDelete type="xsd:boolean">FALSE</n1:purgeOnDelete>
                <n1:rollbackOnError type="xsd:boolean">TRUE</n1:rollbackOnError>
                <n1:runTests minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"></n1:runTests>
                <n1:testLevel type="tns:TestLevel">NoTestRun</n1:testLevel>
                <n1:singlePackage type="xsd:boolean">TRUE</n1:singlePackage>
            </n1:DeployOptions>
        </n1:deploy>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

[image]